# How to solve error messages when logging into Gnome with X2go

Tags: gnome, configuration, x2go

I am trying to log into a Gnome box running Ubuntu 23.04 using x2go (from a Win 10 machine). The connection can be established but a grey Gnome error screen shows up in the x2go window telling me to log in again with a button (that does nothing). Wayland is disabled.

The error messages I get on the machine are these:
gnome-shell:

> gnome-shell[10655]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter
> 44.0) as a X11 window and compositing manager
> gnome-shell[10655]: Unset XDG_SESSION_ID,
> getCurrentSessionProxy() called outside a user session. Asking logind
> directly.
> gnome-shell[10655]: Will
> monitor session c1
> gnome-shell[10655]: Extension ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com already installed in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com will not be loaded
> gnome-shell[10655]: Extension ding@rastersoft.com already installed in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com will not be loaded
>
> gnome-shell[10655]: Extension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com already installed in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com will not be loaded
>
>  org.gnome.Shell.desktop[10655]: Window manager warning: Failed to parse saved session file: Failed to open file “/var/lib/gdm3/.config/mutter/sessions/109263c69ff9341bb168543735357173400000106290000.ms”: No such file or directory
>
> gnome-shell[10655]: Error looking up
> permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No
> entry for geolocation
>  gnome-shell[10655]: error: Unable to lock: Lock was blocked by an
> app

gnome-session:

> gnome-session[12837]:
> gnome-session-binary[12837]: WARNING: Failed to upload environment to
> systemd: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name
> "org.freedesktop.systemd1" does not exist
>  gnome-session[12837]: gnome-session-binary[12837]:
> WARNING: Failed to reset failed state of units:
> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name
> "org.freedesktop.systemd1" does not exist
>  gnome-session[12837]: gnome-session-binary[12837]:
> WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error:
> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name
> "org.freedesktop.systemd1" does not exist
>  gnome-session[12837]: gnome-session-binary[12837]:
> WARNING: Could not get session id for session. Check that logind is
> properly installed and pam_systemd is getting used at login.

This Gnome box used to be a Lubuntu/lxqt box which can still be used in parallel to Gnome.

I can connect to this machine using lxqt both ways, directly or using x2go. Also, I can connect to this machine directly with Gnome, just not when using x2go.

How can I solve the underlying error here?